# Give ReplaySubject value if its empty

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to give my ReplaySubject a value if its empty in component after content initialization, but every time it initializes it with `/api/bulletin/getall` value and it overrides the value that it was assigned before in `onViewChanged` function, how can I check to see if my ReplaySubject has value then assign the value?

```
export abstract class BaseComponent implements  AfterContentInit {
    private currentResultsQueryPathSubject: ReplaySubject<string> = new ReplaySubject(1);
    protected get currentResultsQueryPath(): Observable<string> { return this.currentResultsQueryPathSubject.asObservable(); }

    public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        this.currentResultsQueryPathSubject.next('/api/bulletin/getall');
    }

    public onViewChanged(event: any): void {
        this.currentResultsQueryPathSubject.next('/api/otheragencybulletin/getall');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe `ReplaySubject` gives you any way of accessing previously emitted values (unless you complete the subscription). You could instead initialise a `BehaviorSubject` with `null` and then take advantage of the `getValue()` call to do the value check before emitting another value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by declaring the ReplaySubject as a const:

```
const currentResultsQueryPathSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('..route');
```

Comment: What is more important is that it changed from `ReplaySubject` to `BehaviorSubject` and the initial value is a "real" string now instead of a number. A lot of changes that have nothing to do with making it a `const`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing seems to be similar to what a `BehaviourSubject` is made for. It basically gives you all the functionalities of a `ReplaySubject(1)` and in addition remembers the last value emitted, which can be accessed with the `getValue()` method.

The only important difference is that you would have to initiate it with a meaningful value unless you specifically want `null` to be its initial value.

Something like

```
private currentResultsQueryPathSubject: BehaviourSubject<string> = 
    new BehaviourSubject<string>(null);
```

could be what you are looking for.